# navigationtoolbar pan & zoom buttons/icons DO NOT highlight background when active in matplotlib

Tags: qt, matplotlib, qt-designer, pyside6, matplotlib-widget

i have built an application in python using PySide6 & Qt designer where i added a matplotlibWidget  to window `main_plot_container` and NavigationToolbar2QT to a `tb_frame` that sits on top of `main_plot_container`. i wanted to customize toolbar by moving it out of the plot area and give it custom icons. all good - this is done and works fine. the only issue I'm having is when someone clicks on either pan or zoom button/icon, they not visualally indicate that they are active (DO NOT highliht background when active). this is driving user confusion, tryint to click other buttons not knowing that these buttons are active already. below code snipet on how this is coded.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas

class MatplotlibWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.figure, self.subplot_dict = plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        ....

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.mpl_widget = MatplotlibWidget(self.ui.main_plot_container)
        self.ui.main_plot_container.layout().addWidget(self.mpl_widget)
        self.ui.tb_frame.layout().addWidget(self.mpl_widget.toolbar)
        icons_buttons = {
            "Home": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/home.svg"),
            "Pan": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/move.svg"),
            "Zoom": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/zoom-in.svg"),
            "Back": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/corner-up-left.svg"),
            "Forward": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/corner-up-right.svg"),
            "Save": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/save.svg"),
            "Subplots": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/sliders.svg"),
            "Customize": QtGui.QIcon(":/icons/icons/trending-up.svg")}
        for action in self.toolbar.actions():
            if action.text() in icons_buttons:
                action.setIcon(icons_buttons.get(action.text(), QtGui.QIcon()))
        ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

```
python v3.11 
matplotlib v3.7.4
PySide6 v6.5.1
Qt v6.5.1
```

Comment: show the code for the NavigationToolBar.... or better yet create a [mre]

Comment: @Alexander, i'm using the NavigationToolbar2QT library from matplotlib package. let me add the import to make this clear.

Comment: @Hannibal The imports are not sufficient. Please provide a valid [mre]. Also, a screenshot of the current result and expected behavior would help.

Comment: @musicamante, i wasnt able to create a simple example to reproduce this issue because this requires multiple files implementation - Qt gui. however i got to the rootcause, refer to my answer.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that you'd need to use multiple files to create a reproducible example, as your answer demonstrates, since the culprit is in using style sheets, which are not mentioned in your question, and making your question invalid since it's not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to get to the root cause of this issue. Qt QPushButton & QToolButton styleSheet formatting for other non-navigationToolBar button somehow caused this weird behavior.

```
QToolButton, QPushButton{border: nine;}
```

i solved it by removing QToolButtons from the formatting.

```
QPushButton{border: nine;}
```